# eclipse tomcat why does it keep copying the servlet api jar

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am using eclipse and added tomcat 6 server. whenever i try to start the server it automatically copies the server api jar into the WEBINF/lib folder and the app does not start

```
INFO: validateJarFile(/media/01CB9CAC704E03A0/Projects/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
```

Comment: Could you post the contents of your .classpath file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your project properties and look under Deployment Assembly page. This page describes how your app will be packaged for deployment or export. Take a look at entries regarding libraries. You have to figure out which of those entries points to the servlet api jar and remove it. If the entry points to other jars that do need to be packaged, you will need to split it into several separate build path entries, so you can tell Eclipse exactly what does and does not need to be packaged.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same problem and finally got it to work after looking at this among other pages. I am going to list it here in case other people run into the same issue.

In my case, the myeclipse project was created from a maven .pom file which lists the JEE 1.5 files as "provided" scope i.e. these files will be provided by the container (in my case tomcat 6).  So if I create a war file using maven and drop it in the webapps dir it just works fine.  It gets a little tedious doing that every time you make a change, so I decided to go for exploded deployment and thats when I ran into the same issue.

Since the project file was created from the pom file, these dependencies came in but Eclipse project file does not recognise these as "provided" and not to be deployed.  And TOMCAT is not happy when it finds two implementations of the spec:

"Servlet spec 2.3 sec 9.7.2 recommends … The classloader that a container uses to load a servlet in a WAR must allow the developer to load any resources contained in library JARs within the WAR following normal J2SE semantics using getResource. It must not allow the WAR to override J2SE or Java servlet API classes. It is further recommended that the loader not allow servlets in the WAR access to the web container’s implementation classes. It is recommended also that the application class loader be implemented so that classes and resources packaged within the WAR are loaded in preference to classes and resources residing in container-wide library JARs."

I toyed with the above solution to change my deplyment assembly config but that is not helpful  alone since these jars get bundled in if I select the "JARS from the build path"
in the menu project properties/MyEclipse/Web/Deplyment/Configure workspace settings.
And I need to do that cos I have other dependencies jars (not provided by container).

Solution:

1. I removed these jars from the dependencies in the build path manually.
2. Instead I added a dependency on User Library - JAVA EE5.
3. And in the deployment configuration I removed the option of JARS exported from User Libraries of required projects.

YMMV. But in any case if you read the servlet spec definition above and  then look at the config in your workspace, you can sort it out.

Hope this helps.